# Spiral wont parent to armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, parent, rigify, auto-rig-pro

So I have a spiral acting as an eye and when I parent with automatic weights to my rig, it doesn't spin with the rest of the armature it just stays in place. Is it because of the object itself?

I tried parenting it to the head and joining objects and it didn't work

[image]
[image]

Comment: what do you want to do with this eye? You could simply parent it to the head bone: Select the eye, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the head bone, press Ctrl P (Set Parent to) > Bone. Also, apply the scale of your armature.

Comment: When the model rotates I want the eye to rotate as well, which it isn't even when I parent it to the head bone.

Comment: You can't use weight painting on a curve.  You either have to convert it to a mesh or parent it to an empty and parent the empty to the bone.